# Guess python random seed using current timestamp

Tags: python, cryptography, random-seed

Currently I received a python file. It has following code (interact with a server):

```
random.seed(time.time())
random.randint(0, 10000) // number 1, server gives me
random.randint(0, 10000) // number 2, server gives me
random.randint(0, 10000) // number 3, server gives me
random.randint(0, 10000) // <- this is the number I have to guess, server does not give to me
```

I want to guess the right seed value in order to guess the number chain. But time.time() returns floating point number. So how many number after dot that random.seed will use? I know that it will be much more easier if seed value is a integer, but now this is a floating point number, and I'm stuck.

Comment: You can read the Python source code to figure out the next number. I suggest root/Lib/random.py and root/Modules/_randommodule.c

Answer (score 0):

Edit: my logic was off... woops. Answer is still the same. `random.seed(time.time())` seems to use the rounded number produced by `time.time()`.

```
a = time.time()  # say print(a) produces 1234567890.123456
b = 1234567890.123456

random.seed(a) # this will produce the same seed value as
random.seed(b) # this
```

Comment: I'm not sure that it produces 16 digits just because we type time.time() in console. If you type: print "%.20f" % time.time() , it will print out 20 digits after decimal point. I wonder where the final number that random.seed will stop...

Answer (score 0):

The random.seed() function takes a hashable object and uses the hash of said object for its seed. (An exception is `int` and `long` which are used directly without hashing, see edit below.)  If you want to be able to explicitly set the seed then you need to create a hashable object for which you can control the hash.  For example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3                                                          

import random

class HashMe(float):
    '''                                                                         
    A test for a hashable that can have its hash set by brute force.            
    '''
    def __init__(self, hash_val):
        self.hash_val = hash_val

    def __hash__(self):
        return self.hash_val

a = HashMe(42)
print('HashMe(42) hashes to: ', a.__hash__())

print('\nSeed with a')
random.seed(a)
for _ in range(4):
    print(random.randint(0, 10000))

print('\nReseed with random data...')
random.seed(random.random())
for _ in range(4):
    print(random.randint(0, 10000))

print('\nSeed with a again - et voila!')
random.seed(a)
for _ in range(4):
    print(random.randint(0, 10000))
```

Produces the expected:

```
HashMe(42) hashes to:  42

Seed with a
1824
409
4506
4012

Reseed with random data...
9359
4313
6609
6598

Seed with a again - et voila!
1824
409
4506
4012
```

Having said all that, the length of the cycle on even the crappy Python PRNG is long enough that you are unlikely to ever decipher a sequence based on guessing the seed.

Edit: Of course after putting that together I browsed the Python source and see that if the seed is an int or long it just uses the seed value directly, so there was no need for the hashable shuck and jive to circumvent it.  Live and learn.

Comment: I don't know what you mean. But if I know the seed, I can produce the same number chain. That's normal :)

Comment: Of course it is.  What I was saying was that if you do not know the seed, your probability of guessing it in Python by trial and error before the heat-death of the universe is virtually zero.  You may be able to work backwards to get some hints on the seed by looking at the PRNG source, but it is still a pretty daunting task.  The PRNG in Python is anything but cryptographically secure, but it is far from trivial.